# downloads corrupt files from the file location on server

Tags: php, download, photo

The file moves to desired location and opens in the folder but when i download it downloads a corrupt file

I have tried all the suggestions from the existing posts but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
<?php
$error = "error";
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die($error);
mysqli_select_db($con, 'folder') or die($error);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM documents";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="upload.php">Photo</a><br><br>
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $path = $row['path'];

    echo  $id."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$name."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='download.php?dow=$path'>Download</a><br>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The upload code is:

```
<?php
$error = "error";
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die($error);
mysqli_select_db($con,'servicereport') or die($error);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$doc_name = $_POST['doc_name'];
$name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

if ($name) {
    $location = "documents/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO documents(name,path) VALUES ('$doc_name','$location') ");
    header('location:photos.php');

}
else

die("please select a file");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc_name">
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The download code is:

```
<?php

include('inc/db.php');

if (isset($_GET['dow'])) {

$path = $_GET['dow'];

$res = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE path = '$path' ");

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length:'.sprintf("%u", filesize($path)));

set_time_limit(0);
readfile($path);

}

?>
```

Comment: Just a little suggestion and off topic but since you're just started with php and I see you use `mysqli_*` I strongly suggest to also read how to use prepared statements and take advantages of it.

Comment: Definitely thanks for suggestion, can you help me with this

Comment: when you open the uploaded file, it opens correctly with no issue, but when you download it, it creates issue, right?

Comment: yes when uploaded the file moves to a specific location called documents, in that folder all files are readable

Comment: I have provided a answer, please find my answer, hope, this will be helpful to you.

Comment: it works good now thank you :) will keep imprroving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add these two lines of code after `'set_time_limit(0);'` & before `'readfile($path);'`,  because these functions are necessary for removing unnecessary data or preventing from corruption.

Find the code below, which are to be added:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

I hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: If it works, then mark it as right answer or vote it.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, then please vote it or mark it as right, so that others who are in need & facing the same problem can find this answer here.